Groovy Script Unexpected input ? def @ line , column
I'm trying to:
Conclusion=+def result = []; msg.get('OBX.1') ? def con =''; for(int i=1; i<=msg.count('OBX'); ++i) { con + ((msg.get('OBX.3', i)+ (msg.get('OBX.5', i) ) + ','}; msg.get('NTE.1') ? for(int i=1; i<=msg.count('NTE'); ++i) { con + ((msg.get('NTE.3', i)+ ','};  return con.replaceAll('[\\x00-\\x08\\x0B\\x0C\\x0E-\\x1F]', ' ') 

and I'm getting this :"Unexpected input: '('OBX.1') ? def' @ line 1, column 37."
my goal is to check if msg.get('OBX.1') exist and only if it exist then create the String con and then go to the for loop, otherwise result should stay empty.
what am I doing wrong here?

Remove Comclusion=; why is there a ? in the middle of a line before the
second def ?  Why is everything cramped into one line?

the line is a part of a config to an importer in a system. that's why it must be cramped into one line. conclusion is the result, that the importer needs.

this one for example works :
'''Conclusion=+def result = []; for(int i=1; i<=msg.count('OBX'); ++i) { if(msg.get('OBX.3', i) == 'Beurteilung') { return (msg.get('OBX.5', i)).replaceAll('[\x00-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F]', ' ') }}
'''
but in my question case I'm not sure if OBX.1 exists thats why I need to check it first then create the string and then create the two for loops

msg.get('OBX.1')?.with{con-> ....your wired code here....; return con; }

You are using a ternary operator <expr> ? <expr> : <expr> and it only allows expressions as operands. def con =''; is a statement, so the error is referring to that. Or maybe to the fact that the third part of the ternary is completely missing, so it's not clear what you were intending to do if OBX.1 doesn't exist. I would suggest using if...then...else... statements instead, since your code complexity seems to exceed your reasoning capacity.
